# Chess engine in c or java, performance difference?

Tags: java, android, c, chess

I have a simple chess app based on the Fruit engine on iOS devices. Now I'd like to do a chess app for Android. It seems like I have the following options:

- port the c Fruit engine to Java
- use another chess engine in Java
- use Android NDK for the c chess engine and UI in Java

My question is, assume the same algorithm is used, will there be any performance degradation if a chess engine is ported from c to Java?

I can afford 5% or less in difference (between the c and java engines running on the same device). Thanks.

Comment: The performance differences, if any, will depend too much on the details of the code to provide any meaningful answer to this question.

Comment: Not only the details of the code, but the specifications of the user's hardware device.  There are several iOS devices amounting to less than 2% of all Android devices.

Comment: I'd like to know where there is comparison of related implementations in both languages, such as, minmax tree search, Zobrist hashing, etc.

Comment: @MarsAtomic I am talking about two programs (one in c, one in java) running on the same Android device

Comment: "Port an engine" or "use an engine as-is" hmm .. I know which I'd pick. Just saying. If there are some Java-only options though, I'd try them first and if they are sufficient, just use them to avoid having to create an NDK *wrapper* - depending on what is required, you could write a small facade so that the engine could be "less painfully" changed later. *In no case would I actually port an engine to a different language.*

Answer (score 1):

> will there be any performance degradation if a chess engine is ported from c to Java?

There will be a degradation. by how much depends on how good your low level Java programming skills are.  If you translate the code as closely as possible it will be very similar.

> I can afford 5% or less in difference.

How much difference to you will it make if it is 10%?  The difference in perform between models of phone can be 30%+ if you wait a few moths, the phones will be more than this much faster anyway.

Comment: I'd imagine that there is a larger C/C-In-Java difference on phones than C/C-In-Java difference on desktops (which is all the benchmarks I've seen) .. While I would expect the same complexity bounds, I would also expect a much higher constant factor due to a less sophisticated JIT (or *lack* thereof) on mobile devices. As such, I believe that "If you translate the code as closely as possible it will be very similar" if a fuzzy assertion that should be backed be empirical evidence for mobile (Android) Java/Dalvik implementations.

Comment: Also, while I like the point about the variation (and improvement) in device performance, I think that it misses out on the fundamental (if not perhaps misguided initially ~5%) "requirement" - it needs to run acceptable now and running X% slower *on any particular device* might be the difference between a good experience and a poor one. That said, it really is about how it *does* run (on the particular devices/hardware it targets), regardless of any percentage performance "lost". Testing will show which approach(es) meet the goals.